# Example of how StringFixture works

Tags: json, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

Can someone provide an example of how to use [FitNesse String Fixture](https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/blob/master/src/fitnesse/fixtures/StringFixture.java)?

The following doesn't work:

```
|fitnesse.fixtures.StringFixture|
|value|expected|contains?       |
|hello|lo      |true            |
```

To provide context I'm trying to verify  the value of the `Id` field of a output of a REST call:

```
|Table:smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture.RestFixture | http://localhost|
|GET|/data/1234|  |                                                | |
|let|body      |js| JSON.parse(response.body)                      | |
|let|id        |js| JSON.parse(response.body).Data[0].Id           | |
```

And I'd like not to write any code for this at all if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the fixtures you refer to, but you can do what you describe with my fixtures (https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures).

For strings: nl.hsac.fitnesse.fixture.slim.StringFixture

```
|script|string fixture                                                                                    |
|check |value of             |Hello                      |Hello                                           |
|check |length of            |Hello                      |5                                               |
|ensure|text                 |Hello world!               |contains    |world                              |
|reject|text                 |Hello world!               |contains    |moon                               |
|ensure|value                |Hello                      |differs from|Hell                               |
|ensure|value                |Hello                      |equals      |Hello                              |
|check |convert to upper case|Bye                        |BYE                                             |
|check |convert to lower case|Bye                        |bye                                             |
|check |normalize whitespace |!-   Hello    World    -!  |Hello World                                     |
|check |replace all          |Hello ([A-Za-z]+)          |in          |Hello World|with|$1      |World    |
|check |replace all          |(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})|in          |1975-12-3  |with|$3-$2-$1|3-12-1975|
```

For JSON (which uses [JsonPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2)): nl.hsac.fitnesse.fixture.slim.JsonHttpTest

```
|script  |json http test                            |
|get from|http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two|
|show    |response                                  |
|check   |json path       |$.key       |value       |
|check   |json path       |$.one       |two         |
```

So your REST check would be something like:

```
|script  |json http test                 |
|get from|http://localhost/data/1234     |
|show    |response                       |
|check   |json path      |$.Data[0].Id |1|
|note    |or assign to symbols           |
|$body=  |response                       |
|$id=    |json path      |$.Data[0].Id   |
```

Comment: Question, how would it be possible to set a value to a symbol?
The following unfortunately doesn't work:
    |script|string fixture|                       
    |$someSymbol=         |Hello World                                                      |

Comment: Any method that can be used with `|check|xxxxx|expected|` can also be used to assign a variable. So inside a script table using string fixture you can do `|$someSymbol= |value of|Hello World|`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like contains() returns expected, not true/false.  So the test would be:

```
|fitnesse.fixtures.StringFixture|
|value|expected|contains?|
|hello|lo|lo|
```

Not sure this is a useful fixture, looks like it's just a demonstration sample.